# Is it possible to make two Java interfaces mutually exclusive?

Tags: java

I have two interfaces that should exclude each other:

```
interface Animal{}
interface Cat extends Animal{}
interface Bird extends Animal{}
```

How can I prevent the implementation of a class that implements both `Cat` and `Bird` interfaces?

```
class Impossible implements Cat, Bird{}
```

Comment: Not sure if this fits your use case (I assume that animals-thing is just an example), but can't you make `Cat` and `Bird` abstract classes instead?

Comment: Did not get what your question is? Could you please elaborate a bit? If you do not want to provide the implementation of a interface, do not implement it.

Comment: `// Do not implement this interface together with Bird, because...`

Comment: This question has been put on hold despite the fact that there are several answers the authors of which clearly understood the question. Also non of the voters asked for any clarifications. I believe that this question should not be kept on hold.

Comment: I agree with @Torben and I've voted to reopen. The question is very clear to me.

Comment: Inheritance means something IS something. An interface means something DOES something. A cat IS an animal.

Comment: Exceptions prove the rules: Serializable and other Marker-interfaces *does* nothing, but *is* Something.

Comment: You cannot prevent implementations of a public interface.  Period.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally a dirty solution:

```
public interface Animal<BEING extends Animal> {}
public interface Cat extends Animal<Cat> {}
public interface Bird extends Animal<Bird> {}
public class CatBird implements Cat, Bird {} // compiler error
public interface CatBird extends Cat, Bird {} // compiler error
```

CatBird cant be implemented because:

*The interface Animal cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: Animal<Bird> and Animal<Cat>*

Comment: I don't think this is dirty at all. In fact, it's the clearest answer I've found to this question, top-notch. Nice use of generics.

Comment: Yes. Making the interfaces incompatible is the proper way to ensure mutual exclusivity.

Comment: @yo Seriously? I am afraid of my question and that it has many upvotes. Starting with the idea that a Bird and a Cat is an interface! Let me ask my collegues: "Should a Bird be designed as an interface?" they will shout out "Hell no!". Whenever Cat and Bird are classes, then they naturally are excluded. But other Examples like Immortal and Mortal are better examples for interface exclusion than Bird and Cat. Arrrrr! (not an Arrrr like be mad, an Arrrr like commit the talk-like-pirate-day)

Comment: Semantically, there is nothing wrong with naming an interface like a class as long as identifying instances of it won't change control flow (because, like classes, that violates separation of concerns... sort of). It's hard to know what exactly you are trying to do because the names you use in your question don't speak to the behavior you are actually interfacing. "implements Flying" vs "implements Walking" are not mutually exclusive, either. Birds can walk.

Comment: An example of something I use mutual exclusivity for is for verber/verbee interfaces, where the verber gives itself to the verbee it is given (inversion of control / dependency injection). I then tie these interfaces together with a marker interface that describes the concept. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern

Comment: You could make Flying extend Walking, But then again, airplanes don't walk.

Comment: Excellent solution.  A lot of discussion here has been bogged down over the precise example - Cats and Birds - but my problem domain is more abstract, and I have mutually exclusive interfaces which need to be applied across a family of types.

Answer (score 8):

Here you have a clear hierarchy - a root with branches, and clearly a node (class, interface, whatever) cannot be on more than one branch. In order to enforce this, use abstract classes instead of interfaces.

Interfaces may be used when there is some cross-cutting aspect which may be shared between any of the classes in your hierarchy, and where no two interfaces are mutually exclusive.

example:

```
public abstract class Animal;
public interface CanFly;
public interface CanHunt;
public abstract class Cat extends Animal implements CanHunt;
public abstract class Bird extends Animal implements CanFly;
public class Vulture extends Bird implements CanHunt; //also CanFly because of Bird
```

At least one other has considered this problem: http://instantbadger.blogspot.co.uk/2006/10/mutually-exclusive-interfaces.html

Comment: I did not downvote but your answer but *Interface != abstract Class* so i didnt upvote. And to be or not to be: `CanFly` is a State! I did not downvote because i can throw a IllegalStateException wherever i like.

Comment: I wouldn't say `canFly` is a state. `flying=true` or `flying=false` would be possible states of something which `canFly`, so `canFly` might specify methods `takeOff()` and `land()`

Comment: This is scholar-nomenclature! Compromisse: Let's call it Flyable with `setFlying(boolean)`.

Comment: So the solution was to convert the 2 interfaces which the user asked about into abstract classes?

Comment: Well, it is ''a'' solution. Java classes can implement multiple interfaces, but they cannot extend multiple classes.

Answer (score 3):

The interfaces in Java are born to be implemented. Any class can implement any interface as long as it wants. So, I think there is no way to prevent that case. You probably need reconsider your design.

Comment: I have no idea about a redesign. Please give a hint.

Comment: As shown by others, there are (both good and bad) ways to prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a really, really ugly workaround. Implement a conflicting method signature to Cat and Bird interfaces:

```
public interface Cat {
    int x();
}

public interface Bird {
    float x();
}

/**
 * ERROR! Can not implement Cat and Bird because signatures for method x() differ!
 */
public class Impossible implements Cat, Bird {
}
```

But don't do this. Figure out a better way instead.

Comment: That should probably be in Animal interface: Animal getNaturalParent(); What we are doing here is an ugly hack. We should not try to work it into the actual design. Better keep the hack as a completely useless side method that is never actually used in anything else. And document why the hack exists in JavaDocs.

Comment: Also, not allowing a Cat-Bird animals disqualifies mythical creatures like the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_of_Venice

Comment: Incompatibility is the only way to ensure mutual exclusivity. You call it ugly, I call it elegant!

Answer (score 2):

probably you can not prevent. maybe you can replace `Cat` and `Bird` by an abstract class and the Impossible can only extends one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but if you do not specify that the interface is public, your interface will be accessible only to classes defined in the same package as the interface.

So essentially, you could put your interface in one package, and any classes that you don't want to be able to implement it in another..

Answer (score 0):

Java does not provide a piece of syntax that will prevent one class from implementing two different interfaces. This is a good thing, because interfaces are supposed to let you forget about exactly what object you're dealing with and focus on just the functionality associated with that interface.

In the case of animals this can seem confusing, because in real life no animal is both a cat and a dog. But there is no reason that one Java class cannot fulfil the contract of both a `Cat` interface and a `Dog` interface. If you want to ground this in reality, consider a box containing both a cat and a dog!

Now, as Torben and others point out, you can deliberately introduce methods into an interface that will clash with methods in the other interface. This will cause Java to forbid both interfaces being implemented in one class. But for the reasons listed above, this is not a good work-around to consider.

The best approach if you must force this relationship is the [answer provided by NickJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585939/474189).

Comment: Actually, if the programmer defines both interfaces, he can prevent it. See my answer.

Comment: @Torben Java isn't designed to prevent two interfaces being simultaneously implemented. Sure, you've spotted a work-around, but it doesn't change the fact that Java doesn't really intend for you to prevent this. Thus I think my answer still stands.

Comment: The question was not about whether Java is designed to allow it or not. The question was if it is possible. You are looking for justifications for your answer even though _facts_ prove it incorrect.

Comment: @Torben I've edited my question to reflect the point I'm trying to make. I think it's important to consider what Java allows naturally as a language, because whenever you use work-arounds to fight that behaviour you are often doing something wrong. You make this same point in your own answer.

Comment: This answer is the best answer in relation to OOD. The decision to make java not polymorhpistic is absolutly epic. Actually we expire an advatage of OOD because logic is not enougth, we need a kind of dialetic in programming we did not need before doors behind func-rep-prog (who reactivates the hook-pattern as good practice).

Answer (score 0):

You many throw an exception when a class is going to use it, the UML Diagram would like this
[image]
as you see in the above, the `Possible` would implement either `Cat` or `Bird`, but not both. but this is just a diagram, so the functionality would be like this.

```
interface Animal{void x();}
interface Cat extends Animal{}
interface Bird extends Animal{}
class Impossible implements Cat, Bird{

  @Override
  public void x() {
    System.out.println("Oops!");    
  }}

class Possible implements Cat{

  @Override
  public void x() {
    System.out.println("Blah blah");    
  }

}
class Core {
  private Animal a;
  public void setAnimal(Animal a) throws Exception {
    if (a instanceof Cat && a instanceof Bird) {
      System.out.println("Impossible!");
      throw new Exception("We do not accept magic");
    }
    this.a = a;
    a.x();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Core c = new Core();
    Possible p = new Possible();
    c.setAnimal(p);
    Impossible ip = new Impossible();
    c.setAnimal(ip);
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if a Mutant BirdCat wont life long enougth .... This should be a Compile-time-problem.

Comment: for a `BirdCat` guy, you would have another individual interface `interface BirdCat implements Animal{}`

Comment: I agree with @PeterRader, solving this with a runtime check is not a good solution.

Comment: @DuncanJones so you may need to implement your own JRE

Comment: @user2511414 your comment is too constructive :D

Comment: @user2511414 Yes i can implement BirdCat from Animal ... But `Bird, Cat` is much more specific and exact, assuming its a Child of a Cat and a Bird (my *example* is not very clear and thats why it has been closed).

Comment: @PeterRader it's okay, dude, I hope I could help.

Comment: @PeterRader you asked how to prevent a class to reject implement both of interface `a` and `b`, so this is not kinda possible with current Java specific, but you would reject the `Impossible` at runtime(as I mentioned), so you are saying to have a guy to be both `Cat` and `Bird`, so you are talking opposite now buddy.